# Access denied when using Get-PnPSubWeb

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, access-denied, sitecollection, pnp.powershell

I want to process all websites in my site collection (in SharePoint Online). I wrote a PowerShell script that use client credendtial (AppId + Certificate). Applications permissions are:
MS Graph API and SharePoint API : **Sites.Read.All**.
I'm getting connected using:
`Connect-PnPOnline -Url "Site Coll URL" -ClientID $cId -Thumbprint $cThumb -Tenant $tName`
Then I use: *Get-PnPweb*, it works fine but if I use: *Get-PnpSubWeb*, I got an access Denied 0x80070005. Any suggestions?

I have been able to retrieve subsites successfully using a Managed Identity that has SharePoint API Permissions as **Sites.FullControl.All**. I guess those permissions are needed too but it seems weird to me. I just want to double check, I do not miss something here.